# how to fix this rsrc data in ida pro?

Tags: ida, patch-reversing

[image]

how to find a reference for a string data reference in Ida Pro?

I'm not pro just trying to learn. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The Win32 resource data is usually not referenced directly from the code; resource APIs such as [`FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `LockResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468902) are used to access that data.  You can use a [resource editor](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to view or edit the resources (and then look for their IDs used in the above APIs). If you do want to figure out how the resources are stored on the binary level, check the [PE/COFF specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19509).

Comment: thanks but I can't find it. Any easy way to find it?

Comment: can't find what?

Comment: the reference. Any easy way to find it?

Comment: I can pay for teaching me how to find rsrc refernce to functions